# What does i:nil="true" mean?

Tags: xml, null, xml-nil

I have an xml and it has nodes with i:nil="true" in it.  What does that mean?

For example:

```
<FirstName i:nil="true" />
```

Does that mean something different than:

```
<FirstName />
```

If so, what is the difference?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

This means FirstName is null

```
<FirstName i:nil="true" />
```

This means FirstName = ""

```
<FirstName />
```

Assumption made on FirstName is of string type.

Comment: According to which standard? If FirstName was "", the document would be <FirstName></FirstName>, which is not the same as <FirstName /> (the former is not canonicalized to the latter.)

Comment: <FirstName></FirstName> === <FirstName />

Comment: "The representation of an empty element is either a start-tag immediately followed by an end-tag, or an empty-element tag." - http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags | of course, that has nothing to do with equating `<FirstName />` to mean "the value of the FirstName field is the empty string." There is no "standard" for that...it is dependent on whatever XML serialization tool you are using, but most tools generally behave the same.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe `i:nil` actually means `xsi:nil`, this means that the `FirstName` element is empty, i.e. does not have **any** content -- not even `""`. It refers to the `nillable` property in XML Schema.

Comment: `xsi` has no meaning by itself. It's just a namespace prefix. Most likely, it is defined as the same thing that `xsi` is usually defined as: `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`

Answer (score 5):

nil is an attribute, defined in the `i` namespace. For this FirstName node, the attribute has the value `true`.

It's similar to this, just with different names and values:

```
<form name="test">...
```

Here, `form` is the name of the node, similar to `FirstName` from your code, and `name` is an attribute with a value of "test", similar to your attribute `nil` with a value of "true".

What this means depends on the application reading the xml document.

If I were to venture a guess, I'd say that this looks like part of a xml document defining some kind of schema, and that the FirstName field can have a NULL or `nil` value, meaning empty, or unknown.