# What's the difference between <a_element /> and <a_element xsi:nil="true" />?

Tags: xml, xsi, xml-nil

do you know if there's a difference between these tags on XML/XSD?

```
<a_element /> and <a_element xsi:nil="true"/>
```

e.g:

```
<SpreadCurve>
      <Index>3M</Index>
      <IndexNumber>4587</IndexNumber>
      <BusinessArea xsi:nil="true" />
</SpreadCurve>

and

<SpreadCurve>
      <Index>3M</Index>
      <IndexNumber>4587</IndexNumber>
      <BusinessArea />
</SpreadCurve>
```

Are these **equivalent** ?

If I have a XSD element:

```
<xsd:element name="BusinessArea" type="xsd:string"/>
```

this means that it is by default xsi:nil="false". And this means it will not accept a null value for this element.

My doubt is, will it accept this one?

```
<BusinessArea />
```

What does this really mean to the XSD?

Best regards

Comment: Related question for xml instead of xsd: [What does i:nil="true" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463597/what-does-inil-true-mean)

Answer (score 13):

You get this as your XSD BusinessArea should be defined as nillable="true". Something like:

```
<xsd:element name="BusinessArea" nillable="true">
.....
</xsd:element>
```

What this mean is that BusinessArea element can have null value i.e. empty.

And if element in XML doesn't contain any value then it must have attribute xsi:nil="true":

```
<BusinessArea xsi:nil="true" />
```

This should be invalid :

```
<BusinessArea />
```

Two examples you showed should not be equivalent.

Check this out for understanding xsi:nil and nillable:

http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XMLSchemaTutorial/Output/ser_over_st0.html

http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#Nils

Comment: Hi YoK, thanks for replying. I think I'm understanding now. Pls read my updates on the question body.

Comment: @darklydreamingcoder <BusinessArea /> should generate invalid document. Updated my answer with same.

Comment: Hi YoK, thank you, I've seen your update. Now I understand perfectly. I've updated my question with one more doubt (about non-null elements)

Comment: Be aware when talking about "null value i.e. empty" and "doesn't contain any value". null and empty string are NOT the same!

Answer (score 4):

> XML Schema: Structures introduces a
>   mechanism for signaling that an
>   element should be accepted as ·valid·
>   when it has no content despite a
>   content type which does not require or
>   even necessarily allow empty content.
>   An element may be ·valid· without
>   content if it has the attribute
>   xsi:nil with the value true. An
>   element so labeled must be empty, but
>   can carry attributes if permitted by
>   the corresponding complex type.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil

Answer (score 2):

```
<a_element />
```

is the equivalent of an `empty string` and will render valid against xsd:string, but not against types like xsd:date, xsd:datetime, xsd:decimal etc.

```
<a_element xsi:nil="true"/>
```

is the equilalent of `null` and will render valid for all elements which have nillable="true" in the schema-definition

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that they are not the same. 
At least if you want to validate the xml against a schema.
If in your schema you define the element as nillable, let's say:

```
<xsd:element name="SomeName" type="xsd:double" nillable="true"/>
```

You need to explicitly in your xml set that element to null, like this:

```
<SomeName xsi:nill="true" />
```

If in your xml the element is like `<SomeName />` it will not be valid according to the schema.

Comment: The question is not talking about xsd:double but about xsd:string. Empty string "" will render invalid against xsd:double, but will render valid against xsd:string