# Xml file format and databases

Tags: mysql, xml, database, jdbc

So I am currently working with JDBC to parse an XML file into a MYSQL database. After running tests I have finally finished. Making small edits to my code for clientele I find my self across this XML code. If its a key component and an example be supplied how I can parse it using JDBC?

```
<LineItems>
  <LineItem>
    <ItemNumber>string</ItemNumber>
    <ReceiptType>string</ReceiptType>
    <Description>string</Description>
    <Quantity>decimal</Quantity>
    <UnitOfMeasurement>string</UnitOfMeasurement>
    <UnitPrice>decimal</UnitPrice>
    <Comment>string</Comment>
    <FundingLine xsi:nil="true" />
  </LineItem>
```

I understand completely how the strings work between each entity. But what in the world does `<FundingLine xsi:nil="true" />` do? What does it do inside of the database? Why is it used within the XML code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between <a\_element /> and <a\_element xsi:nil="true" />?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760629/whats-the-difference-between-a-element-and-a-element-xsinil-true)

Comment: @GordThompson I don't think you read my question. I am not comparing it to be equivalent with something else.