# i:nil="true" WCF REST request

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-ria-services, wcf-client, wcf-rest-starter-kit

I am using a data contract in WCF, but there is some unwanted response tags being sent in the xml file, I am not sure how to modify the data contract class so that I can avoid sending that unwanted response field. In the below XML file, all the text which is bolded and italics is unwanted. Thanks.

I have small problem in xml request and data is coming in the following format

```
<resller i:nil="true">
```

What is the reason for this...

Comment: I don't see any bolded or italicised text?

Comment: You probably have a resller reference on your object and that reference is null. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463597/what-does-inil-true-mean

Comment: i am senindin resller name aslo..

Comment: <UserInput xmlns="http://localhost/lms">
  <State>AP</State>
  <ZipCode>500016</ZipCode>
  <Country>Inida</Country>
  <Telephone>9293225135</Telephone>
  <Fax>9293225135</Fax>
  <Reseller>vtsl</Reseller>
  <RegisteredOn>01/02/2012</RegisteredOn>
  <ApprovedOn>03/03/2012</ApprovedOn>
  <Status>1</Status>
  <UserId>1</UserId>
</UserInput>