# Handle "Date": { "@nil": "true"} during jackson parsing

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to parse json using jackson parser. Jackson parse the data successfully, but when @nil:true comes in the json, code breaks and gives an error:

Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token

json string like this:

```
[
  {
    "Users": {
      "UserID": "1",
       "ExpirationDate": {
        "@nil": "true"
      }     
    }
  }
 ]
```

but when json comes like below, then parsing happens successfully:

```
[
  {
    "Users": {
      "UserID": "1",
       "ExpirationDate": "2016-07-07"
      }     
    }
  }
 ]
```

Can you please let me know, how to handle such type of cases.

Comment: What notation is `"@nil" : "true"`? What has generated that json snippet?

Comment: I am consuming a REST service and getting the response from REST service only. Also don't know the notation. @Henrik

Comment: Some body can help me out on this..

Comment: I think that `"@nil" : "true"` is mostly likely the product of some automatic translation from XML to JSON. (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/463597/13075)