# Deserializing an XML into a object: XML element with xsi:nil="true" should have null value (and not empty value) for respective property in object

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

When de-serializing the below XML into Parent class, ElementTwo and ElementThree are empty strings, which is expected. But ElementOne should have been null but instead this is also empty string.

[What does i:nil="true" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463597/what-does-inil-true-mean)

**XML**

```
<?xml version = \"1.0\" ?>
<Parent
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ElementOne xsi:nil="true"/>
<ElementTwo></ElementTwo>
<ElementThree />
<ElementFour>Value</ElementFour>
</Parent>
```

**C# Class**

```
public class Parent
{
    public string ElementOne { get; set; }
    public string ElementTwo { get; set; }
    public string ElementThree { get; set; }
    public string ElementFour { get; set; }
}
```

**When de-serializing the XML into an object, the XML element with xsi:nil="true" is not being converted as null. Instead, it is assigned as empty string. But I've a requirement where it should be converted as null only. Please help me to figure out a solution or point put where I went wrong**

I've given the sample used in below fiddle link:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/VfNJYv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable=true)]
```

above the 
`Public string ElementOne` get/set property

[.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EBjMA0)